# Adding fontawesome icons in latex

Tags: fontawesome, fontawesome5, academicons

I want to add fontawesome icons in the latex.

For example, with `\faCalendarDay` we can add the calendar icon and with `\1faIcon{phone-square-alt}` we can add the phone icon. These both are working fine with some others, but now I want to add this icon:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/user-magnifying-glass?s=solid&f=classic

I tried `\faIcon{fa-user-magnifying-glass}`, but it did not work.

Is there something I am missing? Is there any specific pattern or rule for latex, or there is some limit that only specific icons can be added?

Examples:

[image]

Comment: both the fontawesome and the fontawesome5 package have a documentation which shows which font version and which icons they support.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the icon `fa-user-magnifying-glass` is only available in the pro version of fontawesome5. I have just copied and pasted the information below directly from the manual for the free version of `fontawesome5`:

> Font Awesome 5 is available in a Free and a Pro version. This package uses the free
> version by default. If you own a Pro license and have the Font Awesome 5 Pro desktop
> fonts installed in your system font path, you can use Pro instead. For this, load the
> package with the `[pro]` option:
> `\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}`